# io.Copy cause cannot allocate memory in golang

Tags: go

I use compress/gzip to decompress files

```
func DecompressZip(src string, target string) error {
    f, err := os.Open(src)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't open tar source file:"+src)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    zipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(f)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't gzip source file"+src)
    }
    defer zipReader.Close()
    unzipFile, err := CreateFileAnyway(target) // return *os.file
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't create target file"+target)
    }
    defer unzipFile.Close()
    if _, err := io.Copy(unzipFile, zipReader); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "can't unzip to file :"+target)
    }
    return nil
}

func CreateFileAnyway(path string) (*os.File, error) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(path); err == nil {
        return os.Create(path)
    } else {
        i := len(path)
        for i > 0 && !os.IsPathSeparator(path[i-1]) {
            i--
        }
        if i > 0 {
            if err := os.MkdirAll(path[:i], 0777); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        }
        return os.Create(path)
    }
}
```

this code encounted an error on `io.Copy`,the log:
`can't unzip to file :***: write ***: cannot allocate memory`

The ziped file 300M, unziped file is 5G.
Memory: 2048M.

Comment: It looks `CreateFileAnyway()` returns some kind of in-memory buffer which can't keep all the data in memory (it may be a "real" `os.File` but may be on a file system mapped to memory?)? Or maybe your gzip input file is invalid or "malicious"? As Flimzy said, please post what it is, aim for a [mcve].

Comment: This error is returned by the `io.Copy` function.`CreateFileAnyway` is a function to create file for input such as '/opt/no-exist-dir/tmp.txt'.`CreateFileAnyway`:https://pastebin.com/zc5ARAnX

Comment: If the error is returned by `io.Copy`, then it _is_ a runtime error.

Comment: I've added that function to your question.

Comment: Is your `DecompressZip` function being called more than once?

Comment: At this stage, my best guess is that your system is just running right on the edge of being out of memory. This may be more likely if you're calling `DecompressZip` multiple times (i.e. for hundreds or thousands of files simultaneously).

Comment: It's called only once.Runtime exception(error) is exception which do not need to be catched in Java, so what's the name in Go? panic ?

Comment: I'll try to record some system information.

Comment: A runtime error is any error that occurs at runtime (as opposed to compile time, usually). Go does have panics, too. Your error is clearly _not_ a panic, but it _is_ an error, and it happens at runtime, so it's a runtime error :)

Comment: Hi @magician_john I tried to reproduce the error but am unable to do so, can you upload that `300mb` file somewhere so I can test?

Comment: How much memory is *available* on your system when you run this? You say you have 2GB installed but I doubt your Go app is PID 1, so you don't have the full 2GB available to you.